# Adding image over image after upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a website where you can upload an image, then select another one and add it over the uploaded one. I'm using jquery to make the image draggable and resizable and everything works fine, except that I can't add it over the uploaded image.
Here's my code:

code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.block-add', function() {
    var a = $(this);
    var src = a.find('img:first').attr('src');
    var elem = $('<div class="container"><img src="' + src + '" class="blocks" /></div>');
    $('.block').append(elem);
    elem.draggable();
    elem.find('.blocks:first').resizable();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.blocks {
  width: 10%;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #C8C8C8;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="upload">
  <input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" /> <br>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="block">
  <div class="background">
    <img id="bg" src="" alt="" width="50%" ; height="50%" ; class="center" />
  </div>
</div>
<br/>
<div id="existingImges">
  <a class="block-add" href="javascript:void(0)"><img class="uploadImage" src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/car_wheel/car_wheel_PNG23300.png" width="200px;" /></a>
  <a class="block-add" href="javascript:void(0)"><img class="uploadImage" src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/car_wheel/car_wheel_PNG23300.png" width="200px;" /></a>
  <a class="block-add" href="javascript:void(0)"><img class="uploadImage" src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/car_wheel/car_wheel_PNG23300.png" width="200px;" /></a>
  <a class="block-add" href="javascript:void(0)"><img class="uploadImage" src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/car_wheel/car_wheel_PNG23300.png" width="200px;" /></a>
</div>
```

So here's the result in  this case:
[image]

and here's what I'd like to be after adding a wheel:
[image]

Comment: Have you already tried to generate multiple single divs and positioning on the same location? The css attribut `index` allows to control the order of overlap.

Comment: I don't really know how I should do that.

Comment: Still couldn't find out how to do it. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Troy Bailey and I mentioned, the way to success is the css attribute `z-index`.

Here the changes:

**First step:**

Add this above z-index attribute to class `.block`: `z-index: 1;`.

**Second step:**

For your javascript you have to add some lines which increases the `z-index` attribute s of your created divs, with class `.container`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.block-add', function() {
        var src = $(this).find('img:first').attr('src');

        //New line
        //First, find out how many images has being added and dragged
        var foundAddedDivs = $('.block').find('.container').size();
        //New line
        //Second, get the current value from recently added 'z-index' from fist step.
        var backGroundDivIndex = $('.block').css("z-index");
        //New line
        //Third: Calulate a new value for 'z-index' for each draggable elements
        var zIndex = backGroundDivIndex + foundAddedDivs;
        //Modified line
        //Forth: Creates a new div and add calculated z-index to draggable element
        var elem = $('<div class="container" style="z-index: '+ zIndex +'">
                      <img src="' + src + '" class="blocks" /></div>');

        $('.block').append(elem);
        elem.draggable();
        elem.find('.blocks:first').resizable();
        return false;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.block-add {z-index: 99;}
/* just increase the z-index of the wheel so it can be in front of the car image */
```

Comment: Doesn't work. It's not about the z-index. The problem is, it adds it under the car image.